# How to find the count of sub numbers of size k which divide the number

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, c++14, sliding-window

Given a number n
Find the count of the sub numbers of size x in a number num which divides num.

For example, if the number is 250
and x=2
the answer will be 2
as 250%25==0
and 250 % 50==0.

Can anyone help me out with the cpp code ?

```
class Solution {
public:
    int divisorSubstrings(int num, int k) {
        string s=to_string(num);
        int count=0;
        int i=0;
        int j=k-1;
        string temp="";
        for(int k=i;k<=j;k++)
        {
            temp.push_back(s[k]);
        }
        while(j<s.length())
        {
            if(num%stoi(temp)==0)
                count++;
            temp.erase(temp.begin() + i-1);
            j++;
            i++;
            temp.push_back(s[j]);
        }
        return count;
    }
};
```

this is showing runtime error

Comment: What does the debugger say is the reason for the runtime error?

Comment: AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
======
=32=ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address (pc 0x7fa6deaf8cfd bp 0x000000000001 sp 0x7ffc77769a00 T0)=32=The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
==32==Hint: this fault was caused by a dereference of a high value address (see register values below).  Dissassemble the provided pc to learn which register was used.
    #0 0x7fa6deaf8cfd  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6+0x142cfd)
  #3 0x7fa6de66e0b2  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: SEGV (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6+0x142cfd) 
=32=ABORTING

Comment: Use the stack trace to see what your program is doing that caused the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a number of problems. First, using simple letters for your variables means we don't have a clue what those variables are for. Use meaningful names.

Second, this:

```
    for(int k=i;k<=j;k++)
```

You have an argument to your method called k. You've now shadowed it. Technically, you can do that, but it's a really really bad habit.

But the real problem is here:

```
        temp.erase(temp.begin() + i-1);
```

i is initialize to 0 and never changed until AFTER this line runs the first time. So you're actually erasing a character before the start of the string.